# Why can't I pass a String from env::Args to Path::new?

Tags: rust

Consider the following example:

```
use std::env;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<_> = env::args().collect();
    let out_path: String = args[2];
    let _path = Path::new(out_path);
}
```

Here's the error I'm getting while compiling:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> main.rs:8:27
  |
8 |     let _path = Path::new(out_path);
  |                           ^^^^^^^^
  |                           |
  |                           expected reference, found struct `std::string::String`
  |                           help: consider borrowing here: `&out_path`
  |
  = note: expected type `&_`
             found type `std::string::String`
```

Now if I follow compiler's suggestion, I get this:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of indexed content
 --> main.rs:7:28
  |
7 |     let out_path: String = args[2];
  |                            ^^^^^^^
  |                            |
  |                            cannot move out of indexed content
  |                            help: consider using a reference instead: `&args[2]`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Which, after applying the suggestion, leads me to the previous error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> main.rs:7:28
  |
7 |     let out_path: String = &args[2];
  |                            ^^^^^^^^
  |                            |
  |                            expected struct `std::string::String`, found reference
  |                            help: consider removing the borrow: `args[2]`
  |
  = note: expected type `std::string::String`
             found type `&std::string::String`
```

How can I understand the situation and solve the problem?

Comment: Please provide a proper [MCVE]. It is not clear what changes you have made to the code that led to the second error message.

Comment: @E_net4: I only followed compiler's instructions, as I mentioned in my post.

Comment: I noticed that using .clone() also helps, but I'm lost on why.

Comment: Write the type ascriptions **only** when the compiler cannot infer the types. Otherwise, you lose in productivity and clutter your code with useless stuff.

Comment: What I usally do, when I want a specific argument from env (and only one, because elsewise it will be not efficient) `let arg = env::args().nth(1).expect("Give me an argument!")`

Answer (score 5):

This was indeed an unfortunate sequence of suggestions (use a reference > remove that reference), but this was caused by the manual type ascription related to `out_path`.

You want a string slice, not an owned `String`:

```
let out_path: &str = &args[2];
```

This fits both the restriction of `args` (you can't move out of indexed content) and the requirements of `Path::new`, which requires a reference.

As for your comment, a `clone()` "fixes" the `cannot move out of indexed content` error because it doesn't require a move from the `args` vector - it copies an element from it instead. This fix is of course inferior to just borrowing it, which also works with `Path::new`.

Comment: Thanks! Is there something that could be reported for Rust compiler so that it would give more intuitive error messages in this case?

Comment: @d33tah I'm not sure it is possible to improve this specific case - the compiler is actually doing its best, taken into account the requirements given *specifically* by the user (manual type ascription). My recommendation is to take advantage of Rust's type inference and - in most cases - just let the compiler pick the types; ascribe them by hand only when prompted or confident.